# x86 Asm copy value from register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have such code:

```
mov eax, 0
mov [left], eax
mov eax, [len]
dec eax
mov [right], eax
```

I need to get `0` in `left` and `len - 1` in `right`. But somehow `left` gets 0 and after line gets `len - 1` too. I try to use another register for `right`, but result same.

```
mov eax, 0
mov [left], eax
mov ebx, [len]
dec ebx
mov [right], ebx
```

So, it gives same result.

Full code:

```
section .data
    len dd 10
section .bss
    left  resd 0
    right resd 0
section .text
    global main
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
    mov eax, 0
    mov [left], eax
    mov eax, [len]
    dec eax
    mov [right], eax
```

and at this line I already have a problem

Comment: How are `len, left, right` defined?  Are they dwords (32 bits / 4 bytes each)?  Confusing behavior like this often results from an instruction size mismatch.

Comment: @NateEldredge yeah, it's dd

Comment: Okay, then [mcve] please.  The code you've posted looks fine, so the problem must be somewhere else in your program.  Also please explain how you are checking the results (print statement, debugger, etc) as there could be an issue with that process.

Comment: @NateEldredge check it in gdb

Comment: @NateEldredge forgot about it, fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the NASM manual:

> RESB, RESW, RESD, RESQ, REST, RESO, RESY and RESZ are designed to be used in the BSS section of a module: they declare uninitialized storage space. Each takes a single operand, which is the number of bytes, words, doublewords or whatever to reserve.

So your

```
    left  resd 0
    right resd 0
```

reserves 0 dwords for `left` and `right`, i.e. no memory at all.  Thus they end up at the same address, and you observe that writing to one also seems to write the other.

You probably wanted `left resd 1`, etc.

You may have been thinking of 0 as the value to initialize with, like `dd`, but the whole point of `resd` is that you don't get to specify the initial value; in the `.bss` section it's automatically zero.